# HTML Nested list for week

Tags: html, nested-lists

I'm trying to figure out how to create a list like this using HTML, but I can't seem to figure out how to keep the numbers going...they just keep on going back to 1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3cxs.png

Comment: You'll need to post your [mcve] in your question

Comment: Like below this can be easliy achieved by reading more about [HTML lists](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp). The styling needs [CSS for lists](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest list just by add list tag within another

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    Sunday
    <ul>
      <li>Morning
        <ul>
          <li> 7:00am</li>
          <li> 9:00am</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>afternoon
        <ul>
          <li> 2:00pm</li>
          <li> 4:00pm</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Evening
        <ul>
          <li> 7:00pm</li>
          <li> 9:00pm</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> Monday
  ...
  </li>
</ol>
```